# How to use Cloud Firestore Indexes to query data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've seen the indexing option on the cloud firestore and I was curious how to actually use it in my program to query for users with a certain username or a certain email. I've already made my index but I'm now stuck because I don't know how to use it in my program and I couldn't find anything helpful in the documentation.

[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUNFp.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKsKW.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't need to create indexes unless you are doing some filtering and sorting on multiple fields. Per default firestore has an index on every field. 
If firestore needs a combination if indexes normally it would output an exception that lets you know that and you get a link that will automatically create the necessary indexes. So in your case read the docs on how to create a query:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries